# Trouble making a row of images responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I just want to make a row of images that are responsive. To begin with though I want to reduce the size of the images by 20%. For whatever reason I can't get this to work. I am using the bundler Vite btw and have to store the source of the image in the css like here in the code.

```
<div class="business">
<img class="firstb" alt="firstb">
<img class="secondb" alt="secondb">
<img class="thirdb" alt="thirdb">
<img class="fourthb" alt="fourthb">
<img class="fifthb" alt="fifthb">
</div>

.business {
  margin: 0 7em;
  display: flex;
}
.firstb {
  content:url(./img/business/firstb.png);
}
.secondb {
  content:url(./img/business/secondb.png);
}
.thirdb {
  content:url(./img/business/thirdb.png);
}
.fourthb {
  content:url(./img/business/fourthb.png);
}
.fifthb {
  content:url(./img/business/fifthb.png);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should give the child elements of a flexbox a width:

```css
.business {
    margin: 0 7em;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.business img {
    flex: 0 0 20%;
    width: 20%; //fallback
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="business">
    <img alt="firstb" src="http://via.placeholder.com/400">
    <img alt="secondb" src="http://via.placeholder.com/400">
    <img alt="thirdb" src="http://via.placeholder.com/400">
    <img alt="fourthb" src="http://via.placeholder.com/400">
    <img alt="fifthb" src="http://via.placeholder.com/400">
</div>
```

Comment: Marry me please, it works. yay

Comment: Can you accept my question then? :)

Comment: I do. I will design the coolest three.js elements for you, forever ♡